# Android: unable to parse data through json

Tags: android, json, android-listview, httpclient

i am unable to parse data from server using `json` i am getting data in this format.

```
[{"school":"abc","event":"test","eventdate":"09\/18\/2012","eventtext":"Hello,this is test "}][{"school":"abc","event":"test","eventdate":"09\/18\/2012","eventtext":"Hello,this is test "},{"school":"abc","event":"new test","eventdate":"09\/20\/2012","eventtext":"Hello, test2"}]
```

I am new to `json parsing` here's my code below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.TextView;
import com.appforschools.R;
import com.appforschools.event.Myadapter;

public class event extends Activity {
ListView list;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 @Override

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.event);
   list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

   try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(
                "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        HttpResponse rp = client.execute(get);
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
        System.out.println("----------------------- result: " + result);

        result = "{\"root\": " + result + "}";
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray sessions = root.getJSONArray("root");
        for(int i=0;i<sessions.length();i++){
            HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject e = sessions.getJSONObject(i);
            map2.put("text", e.getString("eventtext"));
            map2.put("date", e.getString("eventdate"));
            mylist.add(map2);
        }




    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("----------------------- 1");
list.setAdapter(new Myadapter());

 }
public class Myadapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mylist.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlistview,
                    null);
            TextView item = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.text);
            item.setText(mylist.get(position).get(
                    "text"));
            TextView date = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.date);
            date.setText(mylist.get(position).get("date"));
            return convertView;
        }


    }


 }
```

when i debug this code then it gets the result in this string `String result = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());` but after the line `JSONObject root = new JSONObject(result);` it shows exception.
please help me about this

Comment: what is the exception exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the response is a json array, you should do:

```
JSONArray root = new JSONArray(result);
for(int i=0;i<root.length();i++){
....
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for reply. `[{"school":"abc","event":"test","eventdate":"09\/18\/2012","eventtext":"Hello,this is test "}]` i have got this only in my list

Comment: ok. these are the events for particular. so how can i get the event of particular date? for example now i am getting the value of only first one, now if want to retrieve events of date "09\/18\/2012" which is in second array, can you help me doing that?

Comment: in the loop for(int i=0;i<root.length();i++) save the content of the json response in a vector for example..then search your date in that vector

Comment: After getting the JSONArray response, when you parse the further response in Array, Take an arraylist there and save the value of all data in it. And then in arraylist fetch the data by comparing dates.